# One specific variable is not define Idon't Know why

Tags: python, class, object, variables, undefined

[image]

I'm working on a python Project which is, to be shor a social study based on a database from pplapi. My first study is about the link between the age of a person an her wealth.From a dictionary, I pick up the information that gives me the age of the people and the one which gives me their wealth, then I put these information into a matrix and I plot everything. My second study is about the link between the happiness and the size of the city in which someone leaves. As before I pick up in the same dictionary the information that I need, I put everything into a matrix and I plot everything. I'm trying  to do some object programming and I'm new to this.

The problem is in my class Zone, I defined a variable called "H" but python says that this variable is not defined. I suppose there is a trick with the "@classmethod" I put above my function but I don't know what to do to fix everything up. Can someone help me and if possible explain me what happens when I do this command? I added an image of the error message that Python gives me.

```
import json 
import math
class Agent: # Les class n'ont pas de () à la fin 

    def dire_bonjour(self,prenom):
        return "Bonjour {} !".format(prenom)
    def __init__(self,position,**agent_attributes):
        self.position = position 
        for attr_name, attr_value in agent_attributes.items():
            setattr(self,attr_name,attr_value)
class Position:
    def __init__(self, abscisses_degrees, ordonnees_degrees):
        self.abscisses_degrees = abscisses_degrees
        self.ordonnees_degrees = ordonnees_degrees
    @property
    def abscisses_rad(self):
        return self.abscisses_degrees * math.pi / 180 
    @property 
    def ordonnees_rad(self):
        return self.ordonnees_degrees * math.pi / 180
class Zone:
    ZONES = []
    MIN_LONGITUDE_DEGREE = -180
    MAX_LONGITUDE_DEGREE = 180
    MIN_LATITUDE_DEGREE = -90
    MAX_LATITUDE_DEGREE = 90
    DDEGREES = 1
    Η = 1

    def __init__(self, corner1,corner2):
        self.corner1  = corner1
        self.corner2 = corner2 
        self.inhabitants = 0
    @classmethod
    def initialize_zones(cls):
        for abscisses in range(cls.MIN_LATITUDE_DEGREE,cls.MAX_LATITUDE_DEGREE,H):
            for ordonnees in range(cls.MIN_LONGITUDE_DEGREE,cls.MAX_LONGITUDE_DEGREE,DDEGREES):
                bottom_left_corner = Position(longitude,latitude)
                top_right_corner = Position(longitude+cls.DDEGREES,latitude+H)
                zone = Zone(bottom_left_corner,top_left_corner) 
                cls.ZONES.append(zone)
        print(len(cls.ZONES))

def main():
    for agent_attributes in json.load(open("agents-100k.json")):
        abscisses = agent_attributes.pop("latitude")  #Latii est couchée....(latitude)
        ordonnees = agent_attributes.pop("longitude") # pour ne prélever que la valeur souhaitée, utiliser agent_attributes.pop(str)
        position = Position(abscisses,ordonnees)
        agent = Agent(position,**agent_attributes)
        Zone.initialize_zones()
```

To make things easier, I put here a git hub link where you can find the code I'm trying to reproduce, you can find also the data base that I'm using.
https://github.com/OpenClassrooms-Student-Center/la_poo_avec_python/tree/04_class_methods

Comment: `H` should be `cls.H` in initialize_zones().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you decorate it as a class method (`@classmethod`) you need to access that as a class variable `cls.H`.

Maybe the below small example would help you a bit

```
class base_foo:

    cls_variable = "I'm in Class...."
    @staticmethod
    def say_static_hello():
        print("Hello...")

    @classmethod
    def say_class_hello(cls):
        if(cls.__name__=="class_foo"):
            print(cls.cls_variable)
            print("Hello foo")
        elif(cls.__name__=="class_bar"):
            print(cls.cls_variable)
            print("Hello bar")

class class_foo(base_foo):
    def say_class_hello(self):
        print("Class foo")

class class_bar(base_foo):
    def say_static_hello(self):
        print("Class bar")


test_foo = class_foo()
test_foo.say_class_hello()
test_foo.say_static_hello() 

test_bar = class_bar()
test_bar.say_class_hello()
test_bar.say_static_hello()
```

**Output:**

```
Class foo
Hello...
I'm in Class....
Hello bar
Class bar
```

**EDIT:**

There is something wrong, So I've modified the code would mind executing with the below file. separate file?

**Why?**

There's a `Diacritics` (Non-Ascii) in your file :) that's the reason. Check this out https://pteo.paranoiaworks.mobi/diacriticsremover/

```
import math
class Agent: # Les class n'ont pas de () à la fin 

    def dire_bonjour(self,prenom):
         return "Bonjour {} !".format(prenom)
    def __init__(self,position,**agent_attributes):
         self.position = position 
         for attr_name, attr_value in agent_attributes.items():
              setattr(self,attr_name,attr_value)
class Position:
    def __init__(self, abscisses_degrees, ordonnees_degrees):
         self.abscisses_degrees = abscisses_degrees
         self.ordonnees_degrees = ordonnees_degrees
    @property
    def abscisses_rad(self):
         return self.abscisses_degrees * math.pi / 180 
    @property 
    def ordonnees_rad(self):
         return self.ordonnees_degrees * math.pi / 180
class Zone:
    ZONES = []
    MIN_LONGITUDE_DEGREE = -180
    MAX_LONGITUDE_DEGREE = 180
    MIN_LATITUDE_DEGREE = -90
    MAX_LATITUDE_DEGREE = 90
    DDEGREES = 1
    H = 1

    def __init__(self, corner1,corner2):
         self.corner1  = corner1
         self.corner2 = corner2 
         self.inhabitants = 0
    @classmethod
    def initialize_zones(cls):
         for abscisses in range(cls.MIN_LATITUDE_DEGREE,cls.MAX_LATITUDE_DEGREE,cls.H):
              for ordonnees in range(cls.MIN_LONGITUDE_DEGREE,cls.MAX_LONGITUDE_DEGREE,DDEGREES):
                    bottom_left_corner = Position(longitude,latitude)
                    top_right_corner = Position(longitude+cls.DDEGREES,latitude+cls.H)
                    zone = Zone(bottom_left_corner,top_left_corner) 
                    cls.ZONES.append(zone)
         print(len(cls.ZONES))

def main():
    for agent_attributes in json.load(open("agents-100k.json")):
         abscisses = agent_attributes.pop("latitude")  #Latii est couchée....(latitude)
         ordonnees = agent_attributes.pop("longitude") # pour ne prélever que la valeur souhaitée, utiliser agent_attributes.pop(str)
         position = Position(abscisses,ordonnees)
         agent = Agent(position,**agent_attributes)
         Zone.initialize_zones()
```

Comment: ok Ill try it out, and I ll answer you later if it works

Comment: i added a "cls." in front of H but it is not working...

Comment: you might have missed in somewhere - please make sure you applied in all places.

Comment: I've editted and add the modified code, can you run that with a separate file. There's a Diacritics (Non-Ascii) in your file :) that's the reason. Check this out https://pteo.paranoiaworks.mobi/diacriticsremover/

Comment: I tryed to check if all caracters were in ascii, and yes it is fine, there is no problem right there

Comment: There's clearly a problem - Can you please try the which EDITED? And posted in my answer

Answer (score 0):

You have defined `H` within a class and need to refer to it as `self.H`. You also have class methods that you need to declare as accepting `self` as the first parameter.

Comment: Well I'll try it out, but in this case why don't I have an issue with all the different variable such as MIN_LONGITUDE_DEGREE = -180
   MAX_LONGITUDE_DEGREE = 180
   MIN_LATITUDE_DEGREE = -90
   MAX_LATITUDE_DEGREE = 90
   DDEGREES = 1

Comment: @973KarljoY  `cls` is right for a class method, but forgot `cls.` in front of `H`, unlike the others.